# Families of Functions, finding critical points

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling with this problem. I'm unsure how to find the derivative.

Consider the family of curves given by:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Find dy/dx and use it to find the points where the tangent line will be vertical and where it will be horizontal.

Comment: Have you learned [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm struggling with it on this problem because of the presence of a and b

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are just constants. e.g. $\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2)=2ax$ where $a$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Differentiate both sides, and use:

$$\frac{d(y^n)}{dx} = ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the derivative of

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

we get

$$\frac{2x}{a^2}+\frac{2y}{b^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$$

To find the horizontal tangent lines set this equal to zero and solve. That makes $x=0$ with the restriction that $y\ne 0$. Now you substitute $x=0$ into the original equation to find the corresponding value(s) of $y$ and ensure they are non-zero.

To find the vertical tangent lines you find where $dy/dx$ is undefined by division by zero or similar singularity. In this case that happens when $y=0$ with the restriction that $x\ne 0$.. Again, substitute $y=0$ into the original equation to find the corresponding value(s) of $x$ and ensure they are non-zero.

Comment: I got that too. I don't know how to move on. To find the horizontal tangent line, you set the numerator to zero, correct? Doesn't that mean that x must be zero? Same for y?

Comment: @boop: See the additions to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, after plugging in 0 to the original equation (for horizontal), I'm unsure of how to find the exact value of y. I can ensure that it's non-zero, but I get stuck at y^2/b^2 = 1, is y=1?

Comment: @boop: No, $y^2=b^2$, so $y=\pm b$.